# Javascript Alert is not working with echo

Tags: javascript, php

```
if (isset($_POST['tambah'])) {
    $id_wilayah = $_POST['id_wilayah'];
    $nama_wilayah = $_POST['nama_wilayah'];
    $_wilayah = "INSERT INTO wilayah_desa VALUES (?, ?, '')";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link,$_wilayah);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $id_wilayah, $nama_wilayah);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">alert('Data Wilayah Desa Berhasil       Disimpan!');</script>";
    header('location:wilayah.php');
```

the Javascript alert is not working. is there anything wrong? I appreciate all answer. thank you

Comment: What's your error? You're outputting the script before the header, which is not possible. Take a look @ [http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: you are header locating elsewhere after echoing. If you have output buffering on this will mean you are redirected to `wilayah.php`, if you don't you should get an error saying headers are already sent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not with Javascript;
It's because that you added:
header('location:wilayah.php');
it will instantly go there without even trying to apply the script
removed it and worked for me ^_^

Comment: <?php 
echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">alert('Data Wilayah Desa Berhasil       Disimpan!');window.location='wilayah.php';</script>"; 
?>

Comment: Welcom..don't forget to accept this answer if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

It should be `type="text/javascript`, instead of language="Javascript. Heck, if I recall correctly, you don't even need this. Try:

```
echo "<script>alert('Data Wilayah Desa Berhasil       Disimpan!');</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
echo "<script>alert('Data Wilayah Desa Berhasil       Disimpan!');</script>";
```

But its likely not working because the header is redirecting you before the script fires